# Dynamic pages in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

I have code for a page, with classes in the form of

```
class page1(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    ...code...

class page2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    ...code...
```

and so on. Then I have

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', page1),
    ('/page2', page2),
    ...(other pages)...
], debug=True)
```

There are some URLs that I don't know, so I can't put them in the application section. I know that they're in the form

```
'/page2/[something]'
```

or

```
'/page2/[something]/[something_else]'
```

and so on, but beyond that, I don't know anything about them. I want to match '/page2/[something]' to the page2 class. I click on a hyperlink, and it takes me to the '/page2/abc' or '/page2/def' page, and I want them all paired with the same page class. How would I go about doing that?

Edit:

I tried to use regex mapping, with

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', page1),
    ('/page2', page2),
    ('/page2/*', page2)
], debug=True)
```

But when I go to any page with the url /page2/[something], it gives me a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: You should design you URL scheme in a general form then look for solutions.  If you want to use webapp2 then you will need to use regex mapping.  ALternately look at alternate handlers/environments like bobo, flask, pyramid.  For instance I use pyramid for cms style apps with arbitrary depth urls that map to object hierarchies.

Comment: See my edit - I'm trying to use regex mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is read [here](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html) and map your urls like specified.
Check out this line:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/products/<product_id:\d+>', handler=ProductHandler, name='product'),
```

this means you'll expect an integer (`d+` means 1 or more number, sequentially, like 1, 123, 12491479 etc) and you'll that information available in your views as `product_id`

This is what `regex mapping` means. If you have no idea what your params will look like, I suggest you store them in a `GET` request, so you won't need to specify a map for those

```
('/page2/.*', page2)
```

is enough to catch a url of the form `/page2/?param=val&param=val&...`

Comment: And yet ('/page2', page2) is giving me a 404 not found error.

Comment: / successfully loads page1. ('/page2, page2) successfully loads page2, but doesn't load anything of the form /page2/[something_else].